# UISegmentedControl containing UITableView and UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I have one ViewController that contains 1 SegmentedControl, which has three segments, and TableView and CollectionView. When the segment is selected, the first two segments show TableView with two different custom TableviewCells and the last one shows CollectionView. Selecting each segemet invokes network functions to download data to populate TableView or CollectionView. The app shows TableView of the first segment by default. The problem is when I launch the app, the app crashes in the numberOfItemsInSection function since it does not have any data to populate. I think this function gets called as datasource and delegate properties of CollectionView are set as 'self'(ViewController). How should I approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you're probably downloading this data into a JSON dictionary or into an array, so you could initially set the table and collection views to have no content like so:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
// note that I would recommend separating these into extensions on ViewController

    var htmlResponses = []()

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return htmlResponses.count
        // htmlResponses is empty at this point
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return htmlResponses.count
        // htmlResponses is empty at this point
    }
}
```

Then, once your data comes in, simply populate the `htmlResponses` array with said data and call `tableView.reloadData()` and `collectionView.reloadData()` for your table views and collection view respectively.

Even if you do not use arrays to store your data, the concept is the same. Use empty elements to populate your views and reload them once you know the data has arrived from the server.

Comment: oh..Thanks. I forgot I declared my array variable like this. ex) var htmlResponse:[Class type]!  I changed it and it works now.